# Simulating arbitrary amplitude pendulums and double pendulums with p5

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm an experienced python 3 programmer but I've recently started focusing more on JS to make client side applications for my website. So I'm not too familiar with advanced level techniques, best practices, etc in JavaScript. I'll post all the code here (HTML/CSS/JS) so you can run it, although the primary thing I'd like some pointers on is the JS. I'm not too focused on framerate/performance (as you'll see I unnecessarily compute certain things more than once per frame for convenience), although any optimizations are welcome. I'm more concerned with having an accurate simulation that works no matter what. I've tested it quite a bit, but there could be edge cases that I missed or other problems with my code. This uses the p5.js library to help draw the graphics. Your help is appreciated! Ok, first the HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="pendulumSim.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pendulumSim.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Pendulum Simulation</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="main-div">
        <div id="gui-div">
            <h4 style="font-weight: normal;">Pendulum Simulation</h4><hr>
            <div class="interface-section">
                <button class="sbtn" id="pause-btn" onclick="togglePause();">Pause</button>
                <button class="sbtn" id="trace-btn" onclick="toggleTrace();">Disable trace</button>
                <button class="sbtn" id="guides-btn" onclick="toggleGuides();">Disable guides</button>
                <button class="sbtn" id="mode-btn" onclick="toggleModes();">Switch to double pendulum</button>
                <button class="sbtn" id="time-reset-btn" onclick="resetSimTime();">Reset timer</button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="interface-section">
                <div class="widget-container">
                    <p>This simulation assumes g=1000 and every pixel is one meter. Click in the pendulum area to set its angle.</p>
                </div>
                
                <div id="single-pendulum-widgets">
                    <div class="widget-container">
                        <label for="pen1-mass-slider">Mass</label>
                        <input type="range" id="pen1-mass-slider" min="1" max="10" value="1" onchange="pendulum.setMass(parseInt(this.value));"></input><br>
                        <label for="pen1-length-slider">String length</label>
                        <input type="range" id="pen1-length-slider" min="100" max="250" value="220" onchange="pendulum.setCordLength(parseInt(this.value));"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div id="double-pendulum-widgets" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="widget-container">
                        <label for="pen2-mass1-slider">Mass 1</label>
                        <input type="range" id="pen2-mass1-slider" min="1" max="10" value="1" onchange="pendulum.setMass1(parseInt(this.value));"></input><br>
                        <label for="pen2-mass2-slider">Mass 2</label>
                        <input type="range" id="pen2-mass2-slider" min="1" max="10" value="1" onchange="pendulum.setMass2(parseInt(this.value));"></input><br>
                        <label for="pen2-length1-slider">String length 1</label>
                        <input type="range" id="pen2-length1-slider" min="50" max="125" value="110" onchange="pendulum.setCordLength1(parseInt(this.value));"></input><br>
                        <label for="pen2-length2-slider">String length 2</label>
                        <input type="range" id="pen2-length2-slider" min="50" max="125" value="110" onchange="pendulum.setCordLength2(parseInt(this.value));"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="canvas-div"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#canvas-div {
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#gui-div {
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #0b3954;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.sbtn {
    width: 90%;
    height: 10%;
    font-size: 90%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #eef5f6;
    border: 2px solid #aaa;
}

.sbtn:hover {
    background-color: #d5f0f4;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

.main-div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: stretch;
}

hr {
    border-color: black;
}

.interface-section {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    /* box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; */
    background: #0b3954;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.widget-container {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Finally, JavaScript:

```
const colors = {
    "black": p5.prototype.createVector(0, 0, 0),
    "blue": p5.prototype.createVector(0, 0, 255),
};

const g = 1000;
const realisticG = 9.81;
const timeStep = 1 / 60;


const simpsonsRuleApproximation = (f, a, b, steps=100) => {
    if (a > b) return -simpsonsRuleApproximation(f, b, a, steps);
    if (steps % 2 !== 0) steps++;
    let sum = 0, h = (b-a)/steps;
    
    for (let j=2; j<=steps; j+=2) {
        sum += f( a + h * (j-2) ) + 4 * f( a + h * (j-1) ) + f( a + h * j );
    }
    
    return h/3 * sum;
}


class Pendulum {
    
    constructor(pivotX, pivotY, massDiameter=40, cordLength=150, mass=1, initialTheta=0, cordColor=colors.black, massColor=colors.blue) {
        this.theta = initialTheta - HALF_PI;
        this.theta0 = this.theta;
        this.lastTheta = this.theta;
        this.cordLength = cordLength;
        this.massDiameter = massDiameter;
        this.mass = mass;
        this.cordColor = cordColor;
        this.massColor = massColor;
        
        this.pivotPos = createVector(pivotX, pivotY);
        this.massPos = p5.Vector.add(this.pivotPos, createVector(sin(this.theta), cos(this.theta)).mult(this.cordLength));
        this.lastPos = this.massPos;
        this.vel = 0;
        this.acc = 0;
        
        this.factor = -g / this.cordLength;
    }
    
    getKineticEnergy() {
        const tanVel = this.getTangentialVelocity();
        return 0.5 * this.mass * tanVel * tanVel;
    }
    
    getPotentialEnergy() {
        return this.mass * g * abs(this.massPos.y - this.pivotPos.y + this.cordLength - this.massDiameter / 2);
    }
    
    getPeriod() {
        // return TWO_PI * sqrt(this.cordLength / g); / this only works for small angles. in other words it's useless.
        
        // instead, compute the period using the elliptic integral from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#Arbitrary-amplitude_period
        // this is adjusted because here g is not equal to 9.8
        const k = sin(this.theta0 / 2);
        return 4 * sqrt(this.cordLength / g) * simpsonsRuleApproximation((u) => 1 / sqrt(1 - k * k * pow(sin(u), 2)), 0, HALF_PI);
    }
    
    getMass() {
        return this.mass;
    }
    
    getTheta() {
        return this.theta;
    }
    
    getRotationalVelocityAboutPivot() {
        return (this.theta - this.lastTheta) / timeStep;
    }
    
    getTangentialVelocity() {
        return this.cordLength * this.getRotationalVelocityAboutPivot();
    }
    
    getCordLength() {
        return this.cordLength;
    }
    
    setCordLength(cordLength) {
        this.cordLength = cordLength;
        this.setTheta(this.theta+HALF_PI);
    }
    
    setMass(mass) {
        this.mass = mass;
    }
    
    setTheta(theta, reset=false) {
        this.theta = theta - HALF_PI;
        this.theta0 = this.theta;
        this.lastTheta = this.theta;
        if (reset) this.vel = 0;
        secondarySurf.background(255);
        this.lastPos = null;
    }
    
    draw() {
        let radius = this.massDiameter / 2;
        
        push();
        strokeWeight(2);
        stroke(this.massColor.x, this.massColor.y, this.massColor.z);
        fill(this.massColor.x, this.massColor.y, this.massColor.z);
        if (trace && this.lastPos !== null) {
            secondarySurf.line(this.lastPos.x, this.lastPos.y, this.massPos.x, this.massPos.y);
        }
        this.lastPos = this.massPos; // don't put this under the trace condition
        if (showGuides) {
            dottedLine(this.pivotPos.x, this.pivotPos.y, this.pivotPos.x, this.pivotPos.y + this.cordLength + radius, 20);
            dottedLine(this.pivotPos.x - this.cordLength + radius, this.pivotPos.y + this.cordLength + radius,
                       this.pivotPos.x + this.cordLength + radius, this.pivotPos.y + this.cordLength + radius, 30);
        }
        stroke(this.cordColor.x, this.cordColor.y, this.cordColor.z);
        line(this.pivotPos.x, this.pivotPos.y, this.massPos.x, this.massPos.y);
        circle(this.massPos.x, this.massPos.y, this.massDiameter);
        
        if (showGuides) {
            fill(this.massColor.x, this.massColor.y, this.massColor.z, 128);
            if (this.theta<0) {
                arc(this.pivotPos.x, this.pivotPos.y, 2*this.massDiameter, 2*this.massDiameter, HALF_PI, -this.theta+HALF_PI);
            } else {
                arc(this.pivotPos.x, this.pivotPos.y, 2*this.massDiameter, 2*this.massDiameter, -this.theta+HALF_PI, HALF_PI);
            }
        }
        pop();
    }
    
    update() {
        this.lastTheta = this.theta;
        if (!paused) {
            this.acc = this.factor * sin(this.theta);
            this.vel += this.acc * timeStep;
            this.theta = (this.theta + this.vel * timeStep) % TWO_PI;
        }
        this.massPos = p5.Vector.add(this.pivotPos, createVector(sin(this.theta), cos(this.theta)).mult(this.cordLength)); // in case the user clicks
        this.draw();
    }
    
}


class DoublePendulum {
    
    constructor(topPivotX, topPivotY, mass1Diameter=40, mass2Diameter=40, cordLength1=75, cordLength2=75, mass1=1, mass2=1, cordColor=colors.black, massColor=colors.blue) {
        this.theta1 = -HALF_PI; this.theta2 = -HALF_PI;
        this.cordLength1 = cordLength1; this.cordLength2 = cordLength2;
        this.mass1Diameter = mass1Diameter; this.mass2Diameter = mass2Diameter;
        this.mass1 = mass1; this.mass2 = mass2;
        this.cordColor = cordColor;
        this.massColor = massColor;
        
        this.pivotPos = createVector(topPivotX, topPivotY);
        this.mass1Pos = p5.Vector.add(this.pivotPos, createVector(sin(this.theta1), cos(this.theta1)).mult(this.cordLength1));
        this.mass2Pos = p5.Vector.add(this.mass1Pos, createVector(sin(this.theta2), cos(this.theta2)).mult(this.cordLength2));
        this.lastPos = this.mass2Pos;
        this.vel1 = 0, this.vel2 = 0;
        this.acc1 = 0, this.acc2 = 0;
        
        this.factor = -g / this.cordLength;
    }
    
    calculateAccelerations() {
        const partialDen = (2 * this.mass1 + this.mass2 - this.mass2 * cos(2 * this.theta1 - 2 * this.theta2));
        this.acc1 = (-g * (2 * this.mass1 + this.mass2) * sin(this.theta1) - this.mass2 * g * sin(this.theta1 - 2 * this.theta2) - 2 * sin(this.theta1 - this.theta2) * this.mass2 * (this.vel2 * this.vel2 * this.cordLength2 + this.vel1 * this.vel1 * this.cordLength1 * cos(this.theta1 - this.theta2))) / (this.cordLength1 * partialDen);
        this.acc2 = (2 * sin(this.theta1 - this.theta2) * (this.vel1 * this.vel1 * this.cordLength1 * (this.mass1 + this.mass2) + g * (this.mass1 + this.mass2) * cos(this.theta1) + this.vel2 * this.vel2 * this.cordLength2 * this.mass2 * cos(this.theta1 - this.theta2))) / (this.cordLength2 * partialDen);
    }
    
    getKineticEnergy() {
        return 0;
    }
    
    getPotentialEnergy() {
        return 0;
    }
    
    getPeriod() {
        return 0;
    }
    
    getMass1() {
        return this.mass1;
    }
    
    getMass2() {
        return this.mass2;
    }
    
    getTheta1() {
        return this.theta1;
    }
    
    getTheta2() {
        return this.theta2;
    }
    
    getCordLength1() {
        return this.cordLength1;
    }
    
    getCordLength2() {
        return this.cordLength2;
    }
    
    setMass1(mass1) {
        this.mass1 = mass1;
    }
    
    setMass2(mass2) {
        this.mass2 = mass2;
    }
    
    setTheta1(theta1, reset=false) {
        this.theta1 = theta1 - HALF_PI;
        if (reset) this.vel1 = 0;
        secondarySurf.background(255);
        this.lastPos = null;
    }
    
    setTheta2(theta2, reset=false) {
        this.theta2 = theta2 - HALF_PI;
        if (reset) this.vel2 = 0;
        secondarySurf.background(255);
        this.lastPos = null;
    }
    
    setCordLength1(cordLength1) {
        this.cordLength1 = cordLength1;
        this.setTheta1(this.theta1+HALF_PI);
    }
    
    setCordLength2(cordLength2) {
        this.cordLength2 = cordLength2;
        this.setTheta1(this.theta1+HALF_PI);
    }
    
    draw() {
        const radius1 = this.mass1Diameter / 2, radius2 = this.mass2Diameter / 2;
        
        push();
        strokeWeight(2);
        stroke(this.massColor.x, this.massColor.y, this.massColor.z);
        fill(this.massColor.x, this.massColor.y, this.massColor.z);
        if (trace && this.lastPos !== null) {
            secondarySurf.line(this.lastPos.x, this.lastPos.y, this.mass2Pos.x, this.mass2Pos.y);
        }
        this.lastPos = this.mass2Pos; // don't put this under the trace condition
        if (showGuides) {
            dottedLine(this.pivotPos.x, this.pivotPos.y, this.pivotPos.x, this.pivotPos.y + this.cordLength1 + radius1, 20);
            dottedLine(this.mass1Pos.x, this.mass1Pos.y, this.mass1Pos.x, this.mass1Pos.y + this.cordLength2 + radius2, 20);
            dottedLine(this.pivotPos.x - this.cordLength1 + radius1, this.pivotPos.y + this.cordLength1 + radius1,
                       this.pivotPos.x + this.cordLength1 + radius1, this.pivotPos.y + this.cordLength1 + radius1, 30);
            dottedLine(this.mass1Pos.x - this.cordLength2 + radius2, this.mass1Pos.y + this.cordLength2 + radius2,
                       this.mass1Pos.x + this.cordLength2 + radius2, this.mass1Pos.y + this.cordLength2 + radius2, 30);
        }
        stroke(this.cordColor.x, this.cordColor.y, this.cordColor.z);
        line(this.pivotPos.x, this.pivotPos.y, this.mass1Pos.x, this.mass1Pos.y);
        line(this.mass1Pos.x, this.mass1Pos.y, this.mass2Pos.x, this.mass2Pos.y);
        circle(this.mass1Pos.x, this.mass1Pos.y, this.mass1Diameter);
        circle(this.mass2Pos.x, this.mass2Pos.y, this.mass2Diameter);
        
        if (showGuides) {
            fill(this.massColor.x, this.massColor.y, this.massColor.z, 128);
            if (this.theta1 < 0) {
                arc(this.pivotPos.x, this.pivotPos.y, 2*this.mass1Diameter, 2*this.mass1Diameter, HALF_PI, -this.theta1+HALF_PI);
            } else {
                arc(this.pivotPos.x, this.pivotPos.y, 2*this.mass1Diameter, 2*this.mass1Diameter, -this.theta1+HALF_PI, HALF_PI);
            }
            if (this.theta2 < 0) {
                arc(this.mass1Pos.x, this.mass1Pos.y, 2*this.mass2Diameter, 2*this.mass2Diameter, HALF_PI, -this.theta2+HALF_PI);
            } else {
                arc(this.mass1Pos.x, this.mass1Pos.y, 2*this.mass2Diameter, 2*this.mass2Diameter, -this.theta2+HALF_PI, HALF_PI);
            }
        }
        pop();
    }
    
    update() {
        if (!paused) {
            this.calculateAccelerations();
            this.vel1 += this.acc1 * timeStep;
            this.vel2 += this.acc2 * timeStep;
            this.theta1 = (this.theta1 + this.vel1 * timeStep) % TWO_PI;
            this.theta2 = (this.theta2 + this.vel2 * timeStep) % TWO_PI;
        }
        this.mass1Pos = p5.Vector.add(this.pivotPos, createVector(sin(this.theta1), cos(this.theta1)).mult(this.cordLength1));
        this.mass2Pos = p5.Vector.add(this.mass1Pos, createVector(sin(this.theta2), cos(this.theta2)).mult(this.cordLength2)); // in case the user clicks
        this.draw();
    }
    
    
}


const dottedLine = (x1, y1, x2, y2, dashes=10) => {
    if (dashes % 2 === 0) dashes++; // make sure it starts and ends with a dash
    let dx = (x2-x1)/dashes, dy = (y2-y1)/dashes;
    for (let i=0; i<dashes; i++) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            line(x1, y1, x1+=dx, y1+=dy);
        } else {
            x1 += dx;
            y1 += dy;
        }
    }
}

const round = (x, decPlaces) => {
    const p = pow(10, decPlaces);
    return floor(x * p) / p;
}

const decimalString = (x, decPlaces=2) => {
    const ending = x<0 ? "" : " ";
    if (x === floor(x)) return (x + ".").padEnd((""+floor(x)).length + decPlaces + 1, "0") + ending;
    return ("" + round(x, decPlaces)).padEnd((""+floor(x)).length + decPlaces + 1, "0") + ending; // +1 because of the decimal point
}

const drawInfo = (paddingX=20, paddingY=20) => {
    let minX = pendulum.pivotPos.x * 2 + paddingX;
    let minY = paddingY + textSize();
    const showString = (label, units, v, inc=true) => {
        const str = label + decimalString(v, 2) + units;
        textSize(floor(min(20, 2 * (width-minX) / (str.length + 1))));
        text(str, minX, minY+=40*inc);
    }
    push();
    fill(0);
    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(1);
    line(minX - paddingX, 0, minX - paddingX, height);
    
    showString("Time: ", " seconds", simTime, false);
    if (mode === 0) {
        showString("Kinetic Energy: ", " joules", pendulum.getKineticEnergy());
        showString("Period: ", " seconds", pendulum.getPeriod());
        showString("Mass: ", " kg", pendulum.getMass());
        showString("Theta: ", " radians", pendulum.getTheta());
        showString("Rotational velocity: ", " radians/second", pendulum.getRotationalVelocityAboutPivot());
        showString("Tangential velocity: ", " meters/second", pendulum.getTangentialVelocity());
        showString("String length: ", " meters", pendulum.getCordLength());
    } else {
        showString("Mass 1: ", " kg", pendulum.getMass1());
        showString("Mass 2: ", " kg", pendulum.getMass2());
        showString("Theta 1: ", " radians", pendulum.getTheta1());
        showString("Theta 2: ", " radians", pendulum.getTheta2());
        showString("String 1 length: ", " meters", pendulum.getCordLength1());
        showString("String 2 length: ", " meters", pendulum.getCordLength2());
    }
    pop();
}

function mousePressed() {
    if (0 <= mouseX) {
        if (mode === 0) {
            const angle = PI-atan2(mouseY - pendulum.pivotPos.y, mouseX - pendulum.pivotPos.x);
            pendulum.setTheta(angle, true);
        } else {
            if (dist(mouseX, mouseY, pendulum.pivotPos.x, pendulum.pivotPos.y) <= pendulum.cordLength1) {
                const angle = PI-atan2(mouseY - pendulum.pivotPos.y, mouseX - pendulum.pivotPos.x);
                pendulum.setTheta1(angle, true);
            } else {
                const angle = PI-atan2(mouseY - pendulum.mass1Pos.y, mouseX - pendulum.mass1Pos.x);
                pendulum.setTheta2(angle, true);
            }
        }
    }
}

/* UI stuff */

const togglePause = () => {
    const btn = document.getElementById("pause-btn");
    if (paused) {
        btn.innerHTML = "Pause";
    } else {
        btn.innerHTML = "Resume";
    }
    paused = !paused;
}

const toggleTrace = () => {
    const btn = document.getElementById("trace-btn");
    if (trace) {
        btn.innerHTML = "Enable trace";
        secondarySurf.background(255);
    } else {
        btn.innerHTML = "Disable trace";
    }
    trace = !trace;
}

const toggleGuides = () => {
    const btn = document.getElementById("guides-btn");
    if (showGuides) {
        btn.innerHTML = "Enable guides";
    } else {
        btn.innerHTML = "Disable guides";
    }
    showGuides = !showGuides;
}

const toggleModes = () => {
    const btn = document.getElementById("mode-btn");
    if (mode === 0) {
        btn.innerHTML = "Switch to single pendulum";
        pendulum = new DoublePendulum(width/3, height/5, height/30, height/30, height/6, height/6);
        document.getElementById("single-pendulum-widgets").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("double-pendulum-widgets").style.display="block";
    } else {
        btn.innerHTML = "Switch to double pendulum";
        pendulum = new Pendulum(width/3, height/5, height/15, height/3);
        document.getElementById("single-pendulum-widgets").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("double-pendulum-widgets").style.display="none";
    }
    secondarySurf.background(255);
    mode = !mode + 0;
}

const resetSimTime = () => {
    simTime = 0;
}

/* end      */


let pendulum, paused, trace, showGuides, simTime, secondarySurf, mode;
function setup() {
    canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth * .75, windowHeight);
    canvas.parent("canvas-div");
    secondarySurf = createGraphics(width, height);
    secondarySurf.background(255);
    document.getElementById("gui-div").style.height = windowHeight.toString() + "px";
    
    pendulum = new Pendulum(width/3, height/5, height/15, height/3);
    paused = false;
    trace = true;
    showGuides = true;
    mode = 0; // 0: single pendulum. 1: double pendulum
    simTime = 0;
}

function draw() {
    if (!paused) simTime += timeStep;
    image(secondarySurf, 0, 0);
    pendulum.update();
    drawInfo();
}
```